# Chrome Extension not firing on interior pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, basecamp

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension for my company to use with the project management system we use, BaseCamp

On the initial load of Basecamp, the alert shows, but when I'm navigating through the site, I no longer see the alert.

**MANIFEST.JS**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "BaseCamp Signature", 
    "description": "This extension adds signature to Basecamp", 
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Title!"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage", 
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "https://3.basecamp.com/*"    
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://3.basecamp.com/*"], 
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

**CONTENT JS**

```
alert('bingo');
```

As a test I used `matches: ["https://*/*"]` in my manifest, and while this would fire on interior pages of all sites, StackOverflow included, even this method did not fire when navigating through the interior pages of BaseCamp

As always, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps BaseCamp simply updates the url and programmatically changes the page content, like YouTube does.

Comment: Interesting, meaning something like React running behind the scenes?

Comment: React is just a framework. I mean using the native api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you lead me to a solution

Comment: Specifically, see this answer: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)